# iPhone simulator show image with wrong dimensions

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, sprite-kit

in xCode5, new a sprite-kit project.

run it with iPhone retina 3.5-inch simulator.

the screen dimensions: 480*320
the spaceship image shows with double size in the simulator.

how to make the image size right.

Comment: I think it is the problem of auto resizing please read this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can check your images size its correct to that particular dimension which you want after that you deselect the autolayout property in identity inspector then give Scale To Fill property to UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be the SKScene's Scaling modes [Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) which determine how the scene’s area is mapped to the view that presents it.

```
SKSceneScaleModeFill,
SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill,
SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit,
SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill
```

You can also hard code the size in the ViewController to test it:

```
// Create and configure the scene.
SKScene * scene = [TheGameTableScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(480, 320)]; //skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
```